# iOS NSXML dictionary not adding to array

Tags: ios, xml, parsing, nsmutablearray, nsxml

I have an instance of the NSXML Parser parsing some xml and storing it in an array of objects. The XML has some image URLS and titles that I am trying to add to a dictionary, and then add the dictionary to an array in the data object. The dictionary is being set properly but it won't add to the array. Below is the xml and code:

XML:

http://www.flashalert.net/rss.html?id=3753

Code:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {

    NSString *string1 = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"amp;" withString:@""];
    NSString *string2 = [string1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&quot;" withString:@"\""];
    currentNodeContent = (NSMutableString *) [string2 stringByStrippingHTML];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementname namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"item"]) {

        isStatus = YES;
        currentPressRelease = [FCPressRelease alloc];
    }

    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"media:content"]) {

        isMedia = YES;

        media = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [media setValue:[attributeDict valueForKey:@"url"] forKey:@"url"];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementname namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

    if (isStatus)
    {
        if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"pubDate"])
        {
            currentPressRelease.pubDate = currentNodeContent;
        }
        if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"title"])
        {
            currentPressRelease.title = currentNodeContent;
        }
        if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"description"])
        {
            currentPressRelease.summary = currentNodeContent;
        }
        if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"guid"])
        {
            currentPressRelease.guid = currentNodeContent;
        }
    }
    if (isMedia) {

        if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"media:title"])
        {
            [media setValue:currentNodeContent forKey:@"title"];
        }
    }
    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"media:content"]) {

        [currentPressRelease.images addObject:media];

        media = nil;
    }
    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"item"]) {

        if (currentPressRelease != nil) {

            [self.posts addObject:currentPressRelease];

            currentPressRelease = nil;
            currentNodeContent = nil;
        }
        else {

            currentPressRelease = nil;
            currentNodeContent = nil;
        }
    }
}
```

FCPressRelease.h

```
@interface FCPressRelease : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *pubDate;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *title;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *summary;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *guid;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *images;

@end
```

FCPressRelease.m

```
@implementation FCPressRelease

@synthesize pubDate = _pubDate;
@synthesize title = _title;
@synthesize summary = _summary;
@synthesize guid = _guid;
@synthesize images = _images;

@end
```

Comment: `media` is the dictionary you are talking about? If yes could you please let me know what is the type of object `images` in `currentPressRelease.images`?

Comment: images is a NSMutableArray. I am trying the dictionaries to the array so that I have an array of dictionaries (image url/title).

Answer (score 0):

You should use an init method to complete the initialization process for `FCPressRelease`

`currentPressRelease = [FCPressRelease alloc] init];`

Comment: Can you please provide source of `FCPressRelease` class? What are the `@property` attributes of `images`?